# Filtering an exact of string in DataTable JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How do I search for an exact match in the search bar of JQuery Datable I tried using fnFilter but it's still not returning an exact match.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#datacal_table').DataTable({"order": [[4, "asc"]]});
    oTable.fnFilter("^"+$(this).val()+"$", 4, true);
  });
```

For example I only watch to search 'active' but what happens is the 'inactive' words also returns in the result. What should I do I need to be able to search only the the exact string.

[image: Post image]

**EDIT**

I tried one of inuka's links [How to search for an exact string in a jQuery DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122994/how-to-search-for-an-exact-string-in-a-jquery-datatable)

and it seems like my text class is interfering with the search, how do I get around this? I want to keep using my class text so that it's colored.

```
<td id="status">
      <span class = "label {{ getStatusColor($data->status) }}"
       id    = "status_{{ $data->id }}">
       {{ getStatusText($data->status) }}
      </span>
</td>
```

when I only retain {{getStatusText}} the search works but when I try to class it, it doesn't.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#datacal_table').DataTable({
      "order": [[4, "asc"]]
    });
    $('.dataTables_filter input', table.table().container())
    .off('.DT')
    .on('keyup.DT cut.DT paste.DT input.DT search.DT', function(e) {
      var term = $.trim(this.value);
      if (term !== ""){
        var termRegExp = new RegExp('^' + $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(term) + '$', 'i');

        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
          function (settings, data, dataIndex){
            var isFound = false;
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
              if (termRegExp.test(value)){ isFound = true; }
              return !isFound;
            });
            return isFound;
          }
        );
      }

      table.draw();

      if (term !== "") {
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery DataTables - Filter column by exact match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609577/jquery-datatables-filter-column-by-exact-match)

Comment: Also you can look under [search exact match and highlight jquery datatable regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783136/search-exact-match-and-highlight-jquery-datatable-regex) and [How to search for an exact string in a jQuery DataTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122994/how-to-search-for-an-exact-string-in-a-jquery-datatable)

Comment: I am sorry I didn't put any more details I tried one of ur links I got it partially working but see my updated post another problem has presented itself.

Comment: Should I make another topic about this?

Comment: No keep it as it is and hopefully someone can help you out. I will look into this too. :)

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319782/using-datatables-how-to-specify-an-element-inside-a-td-to-be-searched) question for your answer and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210730/databable-search-by-only-text-inside-td-tag)?

Comment: First link worked. the  `<td data-search="Text">` method.

Comment: Hope everything is sorted for you. Would you like me to post an answer to close this question?

Comment: Ok sure please do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319782/using-datatables-how-to-specify-an-element-inside-a-td-to-be-searched) post will give you an answer for searching term inside your HTML table structure.

```
$('#datacal_table').DataTable({
   "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": [4],
      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
         if(type === 'filter'){
            return $('#datacal_table').DataTable().cell(meta.row, meta.col).nodes().to$().find('span').text();
         } else {
            return data;
         }
      }
   }]
});
```

According to [Datatables documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) this `columnDefs.targets` will give you the option to match only specified column name values. `"targets": [4]` will only focus on values under your *Status* column.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var oTable = $('.datatable').DataTable(); 
$('.dataTables_filter input').keyup( function () {
      oTable.fnFilter("^"+$(this).val(),0,true,false);
});
```

working link http://codepen.io/subbu1191/pen/GmrvNd

```
1.{string}: String to filter the table on
2.{int|null}: Column to limit filtering to
3.{bool} [default=false]: Treat as regular expression or not
4.{bool} [default=true]: Perform smart filtering or not
5.{bool} [default=true]: Show the input global filter in it's input box(es)
6.{bool} [default=true]: Do case-insensitive matching (true) or not (false)
```

you have to make the smart filtering false in order to get the regex working